# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-5

Hello i am new to laravel and i'm following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E2OiJcmgGp4&list=PLEHx9BVUzI6aCjeA57QNzlGWqI0HV_dbL&index=7) in order to build a student CMS, i have a datepicker and a bootstrap modal that are supposed to popup when i click form buttons, but nothing shows up even though everything seems okay.
I have a master page that contains all the styles and js references
master.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="Creative - Bootstrap 3 Responsive Admin Template">
    <meta name="author" content="GeeksLabs">
    <meta name="keyword" content="Creative, Dashboard, Admin, Template, Theme, Bootstrap, Responsive, Retina, Minimal">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.png">

    <title>Dashboard</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->    
    <link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- bootstrap theme -->
    <link href="/css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--external css-->
    <!-- font icon -->
    <link href="/css/elegant-icons-style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />    
    <!-- full calendar css-->
    <link href="/assets/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/bootstrap-fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/assets/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- easy pie chart-->
    <link href="/assets/jquery-easy-pie-chart/jquery.easy-pie-chart.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
    <!-- owl carousel -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/owl.carousel.css" type="text/css">
    <link href="/css/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/fullcalendar.css">
    <link href="/css/widgets.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/css/style-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/css/xcharts.min.css" rel=" stylesheet">    
    <link href="/css/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- =======================================================
        Theme Name: NiceAdmin
        Theme URL: https://bootstrapmade.com/nice-admin-bootstrap-admin-html-template/
        Author: BootstrapMade
        Author URL: https://bootstrapmade.com
    ======================================================= -->
  </head>
<body>

<section id="container" class="">
    @include('layouts.header.header')
    @include('layouts.sidebars.sidebar')
    <section id="main-content">
        <div class="wrapper">
      @yield('content')
    </div>
    </section>
</section>
@yield('script')
    <script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js"></script>
    <!-- bootstrap -->
    <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- nice scroll -->
    <script src="/js/jquery.scrollTo.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/jquery.nicescroll.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- charts scripts -->
    <script src="/assets/jquery-knob/js/jquery.knob.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/jquery.sparkline.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-easy-pie-chart/jquery.easy-pie-chart.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/owl.carousel.js" ></script>
    <!-- jQuery full calendar -->
    <<script src="/js/fullcalendar.min.js"></script> <!-- Full Google Calendar - Calendar -->
    <script src="/assets/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js"></script>
    <!--script for this page only-->
    <script src="/js/calendar-custom.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/jquery.rateit.min.js"></script>
    <!-- custom select -->
    <script src="/js/jquery.customSelect.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="/assets/chart-master/Chart.js"></script>

    <!--custome script for all page-->
    <script src="/js/scripts.js"></script>
    <!-- custom script for this page-->
    <script src="/js/sparkline-chart.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/easy-pie-chart.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/xcharts.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/jquery.autosize.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/jquery.placeholder.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/gdp-data.js"></script> 
    <script src="/js/morris.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/sparklines.js"></script>   
    <script src="/js/charts.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have another page that contains the form to add a course and the scripts for the datepicker and the modal
manageCourse.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('content')
@include('courses.popup.academic')

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h3 class="page-header"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i>Courses</h3>
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li><i class="fa fa-home"></i><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><i class="icon_document_alt"></i>Course</li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i>Manage Course</li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <section class="panel panel-default">
            <header class="panel-heading">
                Manage Course
            </header>
            <form class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="panel-body" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <label for="academic-year">Academic Year</label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <select class="form-control" name="academic_id" id="academic_id">

                                </select>
                                <div class="input-group-addon" >
                                    <span class="fa fa-plus" id="add-more-academic"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <label for="program">Course</label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <select class="form-control" name="program_id" id="program_id">

                                </select>
                                <div class="input-group-addon">
                                    <span class="fa fa-plus"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                            <label for="level">Course</label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <select class="form-control" name="level_id" id="level_id">

                                </select>
                                <div class="input-group-addon">
                                    <span class="fa fa-plus"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <label for="shift">Shift</label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <select class="form-control" name="shift_id" id="shift_id">

                                </select>
                                <div class="input-group-addon">
                                    <span class="fa fa-plus"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <label for="time">Time</label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <select class="form-control" name="time_id" id="time_id">

                                </select>
                                <div class="input-group-addon">
                                    <span class="fa fa-plus"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <label for="batch">Batch</label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <select class="form-control" name="batch_id" id="batch_id">

                                </select>
                                <div class="input-group-addon">
                                    <span class="fa fa-plus"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <label for="group">Group</label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <select class="form-control" name="group_id" id="group_id">

                                </select>
                                <div class="input-group-addon">
                                    <span class="fa fa-plus"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <label for="startDate">Start date</label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <select class="form-control" name="start_date" id="start_date">

                                </select>
                                <div class="input-group-addon">
                                    <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <label for="endDate">End date</label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <select class="form-control" name="end_date" id="end_date">

                                </select>
                                <div class="input-group-addon">
                                    <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
</div>
                    <div class="panel-footer">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Create Course</button>
                    </div>

            </form>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection

@section('script')
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#start_date').datepicker({
        changeMonth:true,
        changeYear:true,
    });
    $('#add-more-academic').on('click', function(){
        $('#academic-year-show').modal();
    });
</script>
@endsection
```

and the page for the modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="academic-year-show" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelled-by="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Academic year</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <input type="text" name="academic_year" id="new-academic" class="form-control" placeholder="Academic year">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Close</button>
            <button class="btn btn-success btn-save-academic" type="button">Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Nothing seems to work, everytime i get this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined. Can anyone tell me why the datepicker and the modal are  not showing?

Comment: It looks like you're wrapping all of the script tags in an additional script tag? See the `@yield('script')`. Try removing this and the trailing `</script>` tag and re-run the code in the browser again.

Comment: still not working, the @yield('script') is for @section('script') in the manageCourse.blade.php page

Comment: put that code inside of script to file and just use script src

Comment: which code @num8er ?

Comment: @Pain between `<script></script>` tags You've `$(`  jquery's `$`

Comment: Still the same problem :(

Comment: have You created js file? have You included it like: `<script src="/uri/to/that/script.js"></script>` ?

Comment: yes that's what i did

Comment: how about: `@section('script') <script src="/uri/to/that/script.js"></script> @stop`  (not `@endsection`)

Comment: @Pain Your question title is not correct, it's not laravel problem, it's js problem. Also You don't say that that error happen in js (clientside) part. So that's why I was thinking that blade engine cannot parse `$` symbol, that miracle (:

Comment: @num8er i didn't thought it was a js problem because the other scripts work fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your section `@yield("script")` needs to go **after** `<script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>` in `master.blade.php`. Currently, you're trying to run code that is depending on jQuery being available by extending the `master` layout and yielding a section to the extending template, but when this yield is happening is prior to `jQuery` being available.

```
  <script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
  @yield('script')
  <script src="/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js"></script>
  ...
</body>
```

or

```
  ...
  <script src="/js/charts.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
  @yield('script')
</body>
```

Generally, whenever I do `@yield` for `js`, I do it after all other `<script>` tags in the `master` layout, but as long as you know your dependencies have been loaded before they're called, all is well.

Comment: Thank you for your help, it is working for the modal but the datepicker is still not showing